# Managing console of RabbitMQ

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

I want to enable the Management console for my RabbitMQ message broker for that I was using the command on my ubuntu Debian which is

sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

But it shows this error

Error: {cannot_write_enabled_plugins_file,"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins",
           eacces}

Does it because I Screwed something in the installation process?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that user `rabbitmq`:

- has permissions to create a new file in `/etc/rabbitmq`
- file `/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins` itself is writeable